# How to query two types with same field name ElasticSearch with Java code

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have one index - `records` in my ElasticSearch.
`records` has two mapping types - `type_a` and `type_b` and each of those types has `geo_point` field named `location`.

I want to create a query like "all records with a.location in a specific bounding box or b.name is equal to xxxx".

When I'm using the Java code for elasticsearch, in the `prepareSearch.setTypes` I'm putting `"a,b"`, and then in the `setQuery` I need to write "location" and can't write "a.location".

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct your query using `QueryBuilders` in order to express the constraints on `a.location` and `b.name`. It goes like this:

```
// prepare the bounding box constraint on the location field
QueryBuilder bbox = QueryBuilders.geoBoundingBoxQuery("location") 
    .topLeft(40.73, -74.1)                            
    .bottomRight(40.717, -73.99);
TypeQueryBuilder onlyTypeA = QueryBuilders.typeQuery("type_a");
QueryBuilders bboxTypeA = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(bbox)
    .must(onlyTypeA);

// prepare the constraint on the name field
MatchQueryBuilder name = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "xxxx")
TypeQueryBuilder onlyTypeB = QueryBuilders.typeQuery("type_b");
QueryBuilders nameTypeB = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(name)
    .must(onlyTypeB);

// prepare the overall OR query
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .should(bboxTypeA)
    .should(nameTypeB)

// create the request and execute it
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("records")
    .setTypes("type_a", "type_b")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(query)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but for some reason i'm getting an exception when using "type_a.location" or "type_b.name"...when i'm using only "location" and "name" the query is running, but of course it's not good because i'm getting also type_b.location results...

Comment: Then we can modify the query a bit. I've updated my answer accordingly.